# Can't get Node.JS to install on Mac issues with $PATH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, heroku, path

I'm trying to push to Heroku, but the app is rejected `Webpacker requires Node.js >= 6.0.0 and you are using 0.10.30`.  I've just done a fresh install of node.js which should be on my path `/usr/local/bin`.

My path is below, which looks a bit crazy to me, but I can see /usr/local/bin is in there. Where am I going wrong?

```
Simons-MBP:~ Simon$ echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Users/Simon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin:/Users/Simon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/bin:/Users/Simon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/Users/Simon/.rvm/bin
```

Have now installed node via Homebrew:

```
Simons-MBP:gourmet_coffee Simon$ brew link node
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/9.4.0... 7 symlinks created
Simons-MBP:gourmet_coffee Simon$ node --version
v9.4.0

Simons-MBP:~ Simon$ node --version
v9.4.0
Simons-MBP:~ Simon$ sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
Password:
Simons-MBP:~ Simon$ brew link --overwrite node
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/node/9.4.0
To relink: brew unlink node && brew link node
Simons-MBP:~ Simon$ brew unlink node && brew link node
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/node/9.4.0... 7 symlinks removed
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/9.4.0... 7 symlinks created
```

However I'm still getting the same rejection when pushing to Heroku

Should I be adding `/usr/local/Cellar` to my $PATH?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install from brew:

```
$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
$ brew update
$ brew doctor
```

After that add brew location to your $PATH in your .bash_profile:

```
$ export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Search and reinstall specific version (if brew cannot search node, just run `brew install node`):

```
$ brew search node
$ brew unlink node
$ brew install node@6
$ brew link node@6
```

To see your current node version:

```
$ node --version
```

Comment: ok, so just did that and had the following error `Error: The 'brew link' step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink bin/node
Target /usr/local/bin/node
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/node'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite node`

Comment: @SimonCooper for overwrite: `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local` and after `brew link --overwrite node`

Comment: @SimonCooper Ok, first way: `brew link -n node` and manually delete conflicting files, then try link node again.

Comment: `Simons-MBP:gourmet_coffee Simon$ brew link -n node
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/node/9.4.0`

There's obviously something else going on here.

Comment: I'm currently running Sierra

Comment: @SimonCooper Sierra this is normal. /usr/local/Cellar/ - this new package. Just remove old node version `rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node`